Linux ACL of a shared folder for specific group
I need to make a shared folder: I have separated my work between several users on the same computer and need them to access the same folder without restriction. They all belong to a "work" group.
Filesystem is BTRFS, and inside I want all users of group "work" to have full access: erase, add, modify folders and edit files.
Idea
ACLs seemed to be the way to go with the defaults.
SetGID allows to give the group ownership by default.
So I gave the following to the folder (even to others just for the test):
drwxrwsrwx+ 1 user1      work       62  7 mai   13:11 BACKUP

# file: BACKUP
# owner: user1
# group: work
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::rwx
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:other::rwx

Result
If I "touch" a file or create a folder, happy days:
# file: BACKUP/file1.txt
# owner: user1
# group: work
user::rw-
group::rw-
other::rw-

Creating a folder:
# file: BACKUP/folder1
# owner: user1
# group: work
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::rwx
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:other::rwx

As the default ACLs are transferred to subfolders, all goes good.
Problem
If I copy a file with Nautilus or cp:
# file: BACKUP1/file-copied.txt
# owner: user1
# group: work
user::rw-
group::r--
other::r--

So I manage to ignore the user mask with rsync:
rsync --no-acls --no-perms --chmod=ugo=rwX source-file BACKUP1/
However not practial when using the different users on a graphical interface.
So the concern is that I cannot edit the files even if user2 is part of "work" group !
I tried by setting mask::rwx as ACL and default ACL for the BACKUP folder, but no positive result: the rights remain limited by the permissions rw-r--r-- that.
I also tried to set a default ACL explicitly for the "work" group or another group, without anymore success: the permissions act as a mask that limit the effective rights.
Question
Any solution to this ?!
I would avoid messing up with the umask as it can have security implications further.
I tried to set an ACL as mask::rwx but with no effect: the Desktop environment and bash enforce some umask in the operation.
It does not seem one can set a specific umask for a folder.
Thanks in advance !
